# Protractor element finder issue

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm trying to locate the following using `element(by.id())` :

```
element(by.id('#1484755825715-7-uiGrid-0007-cell'))
```

Using Protractor interactive cmd line, it returns `No element found...`

```
> element(by.id('#1484755825715-7-uiGrid-0007-cell')).getText()
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="\#1484755825715-7-uiGrid-0007-cell"])
```

Yet in f12 Chrome console tools, the following jQuery selector finds the same element by div id:

```
 $('#1484755825715-7-uiGrid-0007-cell')[0]
<div ng-repeat=​"(colRenderIndex, col)​ in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid=​"rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'" class=​"ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-0007 amt bold-text sub-total" ng-class=​"{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell':​ col.isRowHeader }​" role=​"gridcell" ui-grid-cell id=​"1484755825715-7-uiGrid-0007-cell">​…​</div>​
```

I also tried using by.css ('#1484...-cell > div'), but that doesn't work either.

So, I know the element exists but Protractor is NOT finding it. Is the id string too long ?

Advice appreciated....

****** UPDATE *******
I was using hash '#' symbol in by.id(), which is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the `id` value is not auto-generated every time?

Comment: @alecxe - yes they are generated for each application instance. @Barney - yes, I believe that was the issue. I had removed the `#` before, but it wasn't working.

Comment: @Barney, correct answer

Comment: Oh nice, I'll warn about this statically in the future to catch this kind of errors early (https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/issues/67). Thanks for the inspiration :)

Comment: @bob.mazzo glad it helped :) By Mistake I deleted my comment though

Comment: @alecxe, my dumb mistake again, but hopefully it will help someone. Thanks for jumping in. Barney needs to add his official answer.